# Sort all the cases of specific variable in descending order but other will remain same using SPSS Syntax

Tags: spss

I have two variables (id and Var1) in SPSS as below. I want to sort Var1 as descending order but other variables do not change accordingly with Var1. i.e. other variable will remain same as before sort.

My data is...

```
id  Var1
--  ----
M-1   3
M-2   4
M-3   2
M-4   7
```

But I want like this..

```
id  Var1
--  ----
M-1   7
M-2   4
M-3   3
M-4   2
```

My Syntax/code is...

```
data list list
 /id(A3) Var1(F2.0).
begin data.
M-1   3
M-2   4
M-3   2
M-4   7
end data.


sort cases by BY Var1(D).
execute.
```

When I run this code it also sort id according to Var1. But I do not want to expand this sort command for entire variables. I only want to sort for current selection variable in SPSS.

Can anyone help using SPSS Syntax?

Answer (score 2):

You Could split the dataset sort the Var1 variable and then merge them together. One way to do so would be this:

```
* create data.
data list list
 /id(A3) Var1(F2.0).
begin data.
M-1   3
M-2   4
M-3   2
M-4   7
end data.

DATASET NAME ids.
DATASET COPY sortvar.

* Delete sort variable (Var1) from dataset "ids".
DELETE VARIABLES Var1.

* Keep only sort variable in dataset "sortvars".
DATASET ACTIVATE sortvar.
DELETE VARIABLES id.

* sort Var1.
SORT CASES BY Var1(D).

* Merge datasets.
MATCH FILES 
/FILE ids
/FILE sortvar.
EXECUTE.
```

If you have lots of variables to delete in the sortvar dataset you could also use the `MATCH CASES` command:

```
* Delete all variables but Var1.
DATASET ACTIVATE sortvar.
MATCH CASES
/FILE *
/KEEP Var1.
```

Alternativly you can use the SAVE command in combination with the KEEP or DROP options in order to split the dataset.